# VBA excel Workbook RefreshAll with parameter afterwards

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update an excelsheet by using the RefreshAll method, problem is that afterwards the sheet asks me for a date before it can update.[The parameter box picture (in dutch)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnzV7.png)

I don't have any rights on the server so I can't change anything there, only in the excel file itself.

I was hoping not having to use the sendkeys class, but at this moment I don't really know another solution?

Thanks

Comment: I think the parameter box is popping up because the query has a [parameter]  --- you can change this to reference a cell and then just change that cell.

Comment: After going through the trouble of editing the paramter from the connections box, I see that the option for "use this value/reference for future refreshes" --- just type ="E$5$" or whatever cell you want in that box and click "use this value/reference for future refreshes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that someone put a user input parameter into the query. 
If we look at an example workbook connection, such as below, we can click "Properties" and explore the query.
[image: WB Connections]

Example of parameter being requested for this example:
[image: date parameter box]

Under connection properties "Definition" tab we can define where to find the parameters. Click "parameters".

[image: Connection Properties Edit Parameters]

And then we change "date" to "Get value from cell" (I prefer the refresh automatically on change option too):

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Thank you very much for the easy and detailed solution!