# dynamic condition in query EOL odbc excel

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I want to load a table data from SQL data bases by Excel ODBC, but the condition "where" i wanted to be dynamic - depended on excel spread cell "A1".

I made somethin like this:
[a picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrC4T.png)

```
select * from tabel where id = ?
```

But this doesn't work and i donno how to define "?" as A1 Cell

Comment: Upload your **picture** here

Comment: Please see a very similar question/answer of mine here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40637025/2446254

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query?rq=1

Comment: yee but I didn't find there the answer. I just have no possibility to choose the parameter for "?" ;(

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following query that works:

[image: Query]

If you add a WHERE CLAUSE like so:

[image: Where Clause]

Then press OK it should prompt you to refresh your query.

At that point you should get the following dialog, which you can use to set your parameter.

[image: Reference Dialog]
[image: Ref Dialog 2]

Comment: yeee i didn't get the third window ya showed :( but nevermind, i coded it in VBA